# CQRS/ES - Way of Communication between two Bounded Context

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

Hi I have a following scenario,

There is two seperate  application

1. ShopManagament - This handle the registration of shop. Contaning aggregate 
   Shop  and other aggregates
2. NotifyService - This send the mail , sms , notification. Contaning aggregate Email
                    , SMS , Nofication

The both application build using CQRS/ES with DDD.

Technology used to build the application is Spring with Axon and for messaging usign RabbitMQ

**Step 1 -**

A shop is registered by issue a command  ShopRegisrtraionCommand (ofcourse this handle by the shop aggregate and change the status when event is fired) , 
 which fire an event ShopRegistratedEvent .

**Step 2 -**

When shop ShopRegistredEvent is fired , then I have a EventHandler which listen ShopRegistredEvent and 
 send the SendEmailVerificationCommand (you can say a request or it act as request )to NotifyService.

**Step 3 -**

The same command (SendEmailVerificationCommand ) is also handle by the Shop aggregate and 
 then shop aggregates fire an event MailVerifcationSendedEvent,
 this event changes the verification status of Shop to "MailInSendingProcess".

**Step 4 -** 
 On other side NotifyService handle that command (SendEmailVerificationCommand or request ) and send the mail , 
 if the email successfully sent then NotifyService fire a VerificationEmailSent.

**Step 5 -**

VerificationEmailSentEvent (fired by NotifyService) is listen by ShopManagment Application using the event listener ,
 then this event listener issue a VerificationMailSendedSuccesfullyCommand for the shop aggregates, 
 and then shop aggregate fire an event VerificationEmailDeliveredEvent , this changes the  verifcation status "MailDelivered".

**Step 6 -**

If the mail sending failed due to any reasons , NotifyService fire another event VerificationEmailSendingUnsuccessfullEvent 
 which handle by ShopManagament event listener and issue a another command VerificationEmailUnsuccessfull  to shop aggregate and then shop
 aggregate fire an event VerficationMailSendingFailedEvent , this event change the status of verification status to "MailSendingFalied".

Here the two BC communicate using request and event.

**Question -**

1. Can we send command to other bounded context as I am sending in my application or there is another approach.
2. Is the tracking the status of the Email sending is part of Shop aggregate or I have to create the another aggregate like EmailVerifcation
   because I have to resend the falied mail using the schedular.
3. Is any other way to manage this type of thing if happinning?

Comment: Whats wrong in question , why negative marking ? Please clarify before mark it negative , it will help me

Comment: Sorry Ashwani, I thought I marked it positively, but apparently clicked on the minus. Fixed it now though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen this back and forth between services for verification happen before, but it is typically a process I'd prefer to avoid. It requires intricate teamwork with services for something relatively simple; the intricacy will typically cause pain in the future.

Now to answering your questions:

1. This should be fine I'd say. A Command is nothing more then a form of message, just like queries or the events in your system. The downside might be that the command-sending Bounded Context should be aware of the 'language' the other Bounded Context speaks. Some form of anti corruption layer might be in place here. See of this as a service which receives the command-sending request of BC-1 in its language and translates it to the language of BC-2. From an Axon Framework perspective I'd also recommend to setting up the `DistributedCommandBus`, as it contains a component (the `CommandRouter` to be precise) which is aware of what commands which node might handle.
2. & 3. This wholly depends on how your domain is modeled. On face value, I'd say a `Shop` aggregate typically isn't aware of any emails being sent, so from that end I'd say 'no, don't include it in the aggregate'. A Saga would likely be a better fit to send a command to your `NotifyService`. That Saga would listen to the `ShopRegistredEvent` and as a response would publish the `SendEmailVerificationCommand` to the `NotifyService`. The Saga is able to either act on the callback of the `SendEmailVerificationCommand` or handle the `VerificationEmailSentEvent` and `VerificationEmailSendingUnsuccessfullEvent` to perform the required follow up logic after a (un)successful email.

Hope this gives you some insights Ashwani!

Comment: I was not using the DistributedCommandBus , actually I am using the RestTemplate to call the public API of the NofifyService. Is this ok to do ?

Comment: I got the the answer. I have to create the sagas and from that sagas I will use either the rest api call to notify service or DistributedCommandBus. Thanks once again. Your ans help to much

Comment: It is fine to call a `RestTemplate` directly i.o. calling a `CommandBus` by the way, but as a rule of thumb I'd recommend first thinking what kind of request your doing. Is it an action? A query? Of is it stating something happened? So in short, is it a command, a query or an event. If it is either of those three, you can benefit from the messaging paradigm en constructs the framework has to offer. So if the call you're doing to the `NotifyServer` is something like 'send email', that to me sounds like 'do this action'. A.k.a., perform this command.